# Swap Selected List Items Between Lists on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have two lists. All list items have unique IDs. The user can select a list item in each list and then clicks a button on top to swap the selected items between the lists. There is a possibility that the lists may contain a single list item therefore I can't use `insertBefore()`.

I use the following code:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    var oldnode = $('#chapters .path');
    var newnode = $('#topics .active');
    var oldid = oldnode.attr('id');
    var newid = newnode.attr('id');
    var oldinner = oldnode.html();
    var newinner = newnode.html();
    var oldclass = oldnode.attr('class');
    var newclass = newnode.attr('class');
    oldnode.html(newinner).attr('class',newclass).attr('id',newid);
    newnode.html(oldinner).attr('class',oldclass).attr('id',oldid);
});
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bx9fsuz/)

This works but I need a better solution because the number of properties of list items may increase in future and will require too many lines.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you provide a working demo, complete with the HTML? That would help us get a better idea of what you are working with and are trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok.. adding that asap

Comment: Are you keeping state in the html?

Comment: I have added a demo. @JoshuaLeonard Sorry I don't understand 'keeping state' but I save the new organization via AJAX followed by swapping list items.

Comment: Have you thought about using Draggable in jQuery UI to move around items from one list to another without needing to use a button.